# DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/javascripts/bootstrap.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net:

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I get this error when I try to load a layout page that uses bootstrap 5:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/javascripts/bootstrap.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I have included the `bootstrap.js` file link in my head tags yet I still got this warning. Can anyone give me a hint on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't currently have a [source map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map) being generated for Bootstrap's JavaScript code. Having one would allow you to see unminified code within your browser's console and locate errors in it more easily.

That said, you can either download [Bootstrap 5 (Beta 3)'s](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map) or ignore the error message, as it will have no realistic impact on any of your users.

Answer (score 0):

follow my step.

1. Download your version of Bootstrap file which you will save in the local directory.
   example : i use v.5 bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/

   note : bootstrap not include documentation Javascript dependencies like popper, so you must download in another link
2. this link popper documentation :
   https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@popperjs/core | v.2.11.6

   note : find the folder by include the popper.min.js file. in my case, I found in it the umd folder.
3. Lastly, you can deploy with local imports. example, I use Vue :

```js
export default {
    name: 'home',
    head () {
        return {
        title: 'APR',
        link: [
            { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' }
        ],
        script: [
            { src: "/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js", type: "text/javascript"},
            { src: "/bootstrap/umd/popper.min.js", type: "text/javascript"},
        ]

        }
  }
}
```

reference sources : https://techglimpse.com/devtools-failed-load-source-map-http-error/